# Unstashing a stash in multiple stages throughout a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using stash\unstash in my pipeline, and wondered could you unstash in multiple stages?

So for example:

```
stage('One') {
  steps {
    echo 'Stage one...'
    stash includes: 'dist/**/*', name: 'builtSources'
    dir('/some-dir/deploy') {
      unstash 'builtSources'
    }
  }
}
stage('Two') {
  steps {
    echo 'Stage two...'
    node('OtherNode') {
      dir('/some-other-dir/deploy') {
        unstash 'builtSources'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So can I retrieve a stash made in an earlier stage, in any of the following stages, any number of times?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can definitely unstash the files multiple times across multiple stages and make the best use of it.